# Cannot Convert From Double To String c#

Tags: c#

I have tried this, but it is giving me an error of "cannot convert from double to string", I wanted to change a variable `ProgressBarMegabyte` to the equation below.

```
ProgressBarMegabyte = (Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte) + Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ProgressedMegabytes)));
```

My Whole Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace SoftwareStoreClientDownloader
{
    public partial class OfflineInstaller : Form
    {
        public OfflineInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormClosing += OfflineInstaller_FormClosing;
        }

        private void OfflineInstaller_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Closed.txt", "true");
        }

        private void OfflineInstaller_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Program Files\\SoftwareStoreOffline"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\SoftwareStoreOffline");
            }
        }

        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
            s.DefaultExt = "iso";
            s.AddExtension = false;
            s.CheckPathExists = true;
            s.ShowDialog();
            try
            {
                BrowseFileTextBox.Text = s.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception dew)
            {

            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var i = 2;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = "Initializing";
            await Initialize();
            button1.Text = "Downloading";
            TotalProgressBar.Maximum = Int32.Parse(Parts);
            if (Int32.Parse(Parts) > 99)
            {
                await Download(
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                    "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part001.exe",
                    MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part001.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                await Download(
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                    "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part01.exe",
                    MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part01.exe");
            }
            var TotalProgressBytes = ((Int32.Parse(TotalBytes) / 1024d / 1024d) * Int32.Parse(Parts));
            var TotalMegabytes = TotalProgressBytes;
            var ProgressedMegabytes = (Int32.Parse(TotalBytes) / 1024d / 1024d);
            var ProgressBarMegabyte = string.Empty;
            ProgressBarMegabyte = ProgressedMegabytes.ToString();
            while (i < Int32.Parse(Parts) + 1)
            {
                if (Int32.Parse(Parts) < 100)
                {
                    if (i < 10)
                    {
                        await Download(
                            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                            "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part0" + i + ".rar",
                            MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part0" + i + ".rar");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Download(
                            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                            "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar",
                            MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar");
                    }
                }
                else if (Int32.Parse(Parts) > 99)
                {
                    if (i < 10 && i < 100)
                    {
                        await Download(
                            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                            "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part00" + i + ".rar",
                            MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part00" + i + ".rar");
                    }
                    else if(i > 10 && i < 100)
                    {
                        await Download(
                            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                            "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part0" + i + ".rar",
                            MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part0" + i + ".rar");
                    }
                    else if (i > 99)
                    {
                        await Download(
                            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                            "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar",
                            MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar");
                    }
                }
                else if (Int32.Parse(Parts) < 10)
                {
                    await Download(
                        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline" + Database +
                        "/master/SoftwareStore" + Version + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar",
                        MainDirectory + "\\" + "Setup-Files.part" + i + ".rar");
                }

                DownloadProgressLabel.Text = "Status: (" + i + "/" + Parts + ")";
                if (i < TotalProgressBar.Maximum)
                {
                    TotalProgressBar.Value = i;
                }

                if (first == false)
                {
                    TotalProgressLabel.Text = "(" + ProgressBarMegabyte + " MB / " + TotalMegabytes + " MB)";
                    first = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalProgressLabel.Text = "(" + ProgressBarMegabyte + " MB / " + TotalMegabytes + " MB)";
                }

                int Equation = Convert.ToInt32(Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte) +
                                       Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ProgressedMegabytes)));
                ProgressBarMegabyte = Equation.ToString();

                i++;
            }

            if (Int32.Parse(Parts) > 99)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\SoftwareStoreOffline\Setup-Files.part001.exe").WaitForExit();
                });
            }
            else if (Int32.Parse(Parts) < 100)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\SoftwareStoreOffline\Setup-Files.part01.exe");
                });
            }
            else if(Int32.Parse(Parts) < 10)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\SoftwareStoreOffline\Setup-Files.part1.exe");
                });
            }
        }

        private bool first = false;
        private string MainDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\SoftwareStoreOffline";
        private string TotalBytes = string.Empty;
        private async Task Download(string link, string Filename)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), Filename);
                while (client.IsBusy)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {

            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TotalBytes = e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString();
            DownloadProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private string Parts = string.Empty;
        private string Database = string.Empty;
        private string Version = string.Empty;
        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                await Download(
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt",
                    MainDirectory + "\\OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt");
                await Download(
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineParts.txt",
                    MainDirectory + "\\OfflineParts.txt");
                await Download(
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineVersion.txt",
                    MainDirectory + "\\OfflineVersion.txt");
                Parts = File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineParts.txt").First();
                Database = File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt").First();
                Version = File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineVersion.txt").First();
            }
            catch (Exception dew)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dew);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use that equation, because I wanted to solve the progress bar, which I eventually figured out. I used the `int`

Comment: What is `ProgressedMegabytes`? And why are you converting it to a `string` and then trying to `Parse` it?

Comment: ``ProgressedMegabytes`` is a double

Comment: What is the data type of `ProgressBarMegabyte ` (without the `s` on the end)? Is it a string?

Comment: Its better to add to the question the whole process of that equation

Comment: Hey bud, we need you to give us some more information. For the most part we are just taking shots in the dark at some of the information you've given us. Show us more of your code in the post so we can actually give you useful information

Comment: please elaborate your code example. Assign a representative value to both ProgressBarMegabyte and ProgressBarMegabytes so we can clearly see what you are doing.

Comment: @JacksonChung - There's no point doing `Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ProgressedMegabytes))` when `ProgressedMegabytes` would do the same thing.

Comment: @JacksonChung - You have a bunch of things to tidy up here: Don't write `while (client.IsBusy) { await Task.Delay(10); }`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Convert.ToString()

you can simply do: ProgressedMegabytes.ToString()

Comment: but im doing an equation

Comment: Ya beat me to the punch haha. OP listen to this guy.

Comment: ``ProgressBarMegabyte = (Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte) + ProgressedMegabytes.ToString());`` Now gives me ``System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
``

Answer (score 1):

You problem is with different types:

- ProgressBarMegabyte is a string
- ProgressedMegabytes is double as you said.

Then your assignent is:

```
sting = int + double
```

Hence you error. To fix it - simply convert the result to string:

```
double ProgressedMegabytes = 1.5;
string ProgressBarMegabyte = "83345603 .....................";

ProgressBarMegabyte = (Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte.TrimEnd('.')) + ProgressedMegabytes).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(ProgressBarMegabyte); // 83345604.5
```

And be careful with the value of `ProgressBarMegabyte` - you are working with an assumption that it is a number!

Comment: Still gives me `System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
`

Comment: What is the value of `ProgressBarMegabyte`? Can it be parsed as int?

Comment: Or if i cant solve it, I would "remove" the decimal, and tell people that the number has a "invisible" decimal somewhere. Thats only if theres no solution to it

Comment: 83345603   .....................

Comment: with dots at the end? If so, you can strip them with `Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte.TrimEnd('.')`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question - I just wanted to post a refactored version of your code that might help you to move forward.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var i = 2;
    await Initialize();

    var name = Parts > 99 ? "part001" : "part01";
    await Download($"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline{Database}/master/SoftwareStore{Version}Setup-Files.{name}.exe", $"{MainDirectory}\\Setup-Files.{name}.exe");

    var format = new string('0', Parts.ToString().Length)
    while (i < Parts + 1)
    {
        await Download($"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreOffline{Database}/master/SoftwareStore{Version}Setup-Files.part{i.ToString(format)}.rar", $"{MainDirectory}\\Setup-Files.{i.ToString(format)}.rar");
        i++;
    }

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Process.Start($@"C:\Program Files\SoftwareStoreOffline\Setup-Files.part{1.ToString(format)}.exe").WaitForExit();
    });

}

private string MainDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\SoftwareStoreOffline";
private async Task Download(string link, string Filename)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(link, Filename);
    }
}

private int Parts;
private string Database = string.Empty;
private string Version = string.Empty;
private async Task Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        await Download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt", MainDirectory + "\\OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt");
        await Download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineParts.txt", MainDirectory + "\\OfflineParts.txt");
        await Download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CNTowerGUN/SoftwareStoreClientDownloader/master/OfflineVersion.txt", MainDirectory + "\\OfflineVersion.txt");
        Parts = int.Parse(File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineParts.txt").First());
        Database = File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineDatabaseNumber.txt").First();
        Version = File.ReadLines(MainDirectory + "\\OfflineVersion.txt").First();
    }
    catch (Exception dew)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dew);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem myself using cheap methods:

```
int Equation = Convert.ToInt32(Int32.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte)
    + Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ProgressedMegabytes)));                
ProgressBarMegabyte = Equation.ToString();
```

Comment: You could write this first line as `int Equation = int.Parse(ProgressBarMegabyte + (int)ProgressedMegabytes);`.